# Attaching an Google AdWords conversion to a campaign

Tags: google-ads

In Google AdWords, I've created a conversion and put the script onto my webpage but now I don't know how to connect this conversion to a campaign, so that it shows up on the table for the campaign data.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will automatically. The conversion-tag is based on an account level (at least until now) and once a conversion through any keyword in any campaign has taken place, it will automatically show in your account.

Comment: BTW the columns should already show up, if not you can modify the columns in your campaign tab